# ExtJs getting error using grid as component

Tags: extjs4

I'm new to ExtJs, and I'm trying to use a grid as a component, but it doesn't seem to initialize when I instantiate it.

It throws this error:

```
c is not a constructor
http://localhost/xv1/extjs/ext-debug.js
Line 6456
```

the error occurs on this line:

```
var gridVoucher = Ext.create('accountant.gridVoucher');
```

Here is the complete code: http://pastebin.com/42sfGVvU

Comment: Actually, besides what @nscrob said about callParent, you can achieve the same result by calling `Ext.widget('accountant.gridVoucher')`, oh, and BTW, Ext.create accepts a config parameter but doesn't require one, you can do: `Ext.create('accountant.gridVoucher')` without any problems.

Comment: hello! yes, but the thing i try to do it and i get the same error. I seriously dont know what else to do. seems like the grid component doesnt initialize, and i dont know why.

Comment: Change constructor to initComponent in the gridVoucher definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need initComponent , as other people have mentioned.  Also, you implement grid extensions much differently than I would.  For example, I have never once used `Ext.apply` in my life.  I am not sure if you are doing it wrong, or just a correct but different way, but here is the method I use that works.

```
Ext.define('App.teams',
{
    extend: 'App.gridBaseClass',//custom base class extends 'Ext.grid.Panel'  
    initComponent: function(config) 
    {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    property:'default'
    constructor     : function(config)
    {  
         config.columns = [...];
         config.title = 'my title';
         if(!config.width)config.width=300;//something we are allowed to override

         //set other configs as needed, whatever you would send to grid.Panel 

         //example of setting global data from config input
         if(config.property) this.property=config.property;

         this.callParent(arguments);   
    }
});
```

Important things to note are callParent and initComponent.  I hope this helped, or was at least interesting to compare a different method.

EDIT:Just to confirm, with this method we can create grids the exact same way you do, with 
simply

```
var grid = Ext.create('App.teams');
```